# Sanitizing text fields in array

Tags: php, metabox, validation

I tried this code to create some meta boxes is all working fine, the problem I am facing is how to sanitize the text fields and update post meta

```
    function Print_price_fileds($cnt, $p = null) {
    if ($p === null){
    $a = $b = $c = '';
    }else{
    $a = $p['n'];
    $b = $p['d'];
    $c = $p['p'];
    }
    return  <<<HTML
    <li>
    <label>Nr :</label>
    <input type="text" name="price_data[$cnt][n]" size="10" value="$a"/>

    <label>Description :</label>
    <input type="text" name="price_data[$cnt][d]" size="50" value="$b"/>

    <label>Price :</label>
    <input type="text" name="price_data[$cnt][p]" size="20" value="$c"/>
    <span class="remove">Remove</span>
    </li>
    HTML
    ;
    }


    //add custom field - price
    add_action("add_meta_boxes", "object_init");

    function object_init(){
      add_meta_box("price_meta_id", "Price fields :","price_meta", "post", 
    "normal", "low");

    }

    function price_meta(){
     global $post;

    $data = get_post_meta($post->ID,"price_data",true);
     echo '<div>';
     echo '<ul id="price_items">';
     $c = 0;
     if (count($data) > 0){
        foreach((array)$data as $p ){
            if (isset($p['p']) || isset($p['d'])|| isset($p['n'])){
                echo Print_price_fileds($c,$p);
                $c = $c +1;
            }
        }

    }
    echo '</ul>';

    ?>
        <span id="here"></span>
        <span class="add"><?php echo __('Add Price Data'); ?></span>
        <script>
            var $ =jQuery.noConflict();
                $(document).ready(function() {
                var count = <?php echo $c - 1; ?>; // substract 1 from $c
                $(".add").click(function() {
                    count = count + 1;
                    //$('#price_items').append('<li><label>Nr :</label><input type="text" name="price_data[' + count + '][n]" size="10" value=""/><label>Description :</label><input type="text" name="price_data[' + count + '][d]" size="50" value=""/><label>Price :</label><input type="text" name="price_data[' + count + '][p]" size="20" value=""/><span class="remove">Remove</span></li>');
                   $('#price_items').append('<? echo implode('',explode("\n",Print_price_fileds('count'))); ?>'.replace(/count/g, count));
                    return false;
                });
                $(".remove").live('click', function() {
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>#price_items {list-style: none;}</style>
    <?php
    echo '</div>';
}


    //Save product price
    add_action('save_post', 'save_detailss');

    function save_detailss($post_id){ 
    global $post;


    // to prevent metadata or custom fields from disappearing... 
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
    return $post_id; 
    // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
    if (isset($_POST['price_data'])){
        $data = $_POST['price_data'];
        update_post_meta($post_id,'price_data',$data);
    }else{
        delete_post_meta($post_id,'price_data');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to sanitize text fields within WordPress is to use [`sanitize_text_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/) function:

```
$data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['key'] );
```

Additionally, if you register the meta field properly width [`register_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_meta/) function, you can define the sanitize callback and the expected data type as well. For example:

```
add_action( 'init', 'cyb_register_meta_fields' );
function cyb_register_meta_fields() {
  $args = array(
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field'
  );
  register_meta( 'post', 'key', $args );
}
```

By using `register_meta()` you don't need to sanitize the meta field every time you upadate or create it, just use `upadate_post_meta()`/`add_post_meta()` and the sanitize callback will be used automatically. So, if your meta field is an array, it could be something like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'cyb_register_meta_fields' );
function cyb_register_meta_fields() {

  $args = array(
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_price_field'
  );

  register_meta( 'post', 'price_data', $args );

}

function sanitize_price_field( $meta_value ) {

  foreach ( (array) $meta_value as $k => $v ) {
    if ( is_array( $v ) ) {
      $meta_value[$k] =  sanitize_price_field( $v );
    } else {
      $meta_value[$k] = sanitize_text_field( $v );
    }
  }

  return $meta_value;

}
```

Comment: it didn't work, but thank you any way !!

Comment: Can you explain what "didn't work" exactly means? Can you update the question with the exact code you have tried? I use a similar approach everytime I create a custom field and it works perfectly.

Comment: Well, the `array_walk_recursive()` callback needs to get the data passed by reference in order to change the original array, I think that was the problem with the answer not working. Code updated.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress use `add_magic_quotes()` to escape incoming data from `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE`and `$_SERVER`in load.php on line 647. You can use structur of this function to build Your own function which can sanitize every element in array:

```
function add_magic_quotes( $array ) {
    foreach ( (array) $array as $k => $v ) {
        if ( is_array( $v ) ) {
            $array[$k] = add_magic_quotes( $v );
        } else {
            $array[$k] = addslashes( $v );
    }
}
return $array;
```

}

in place of addslashes You can use your needed function. 
Example:

```
function sanitize_price_array( $array ) {
   foreach ( (array) $array as $k => $v ) {
      if ( is_array( $v ) ) {
          $array[$k] =  sanitize_price_array( $v );
      } else {
          $array[$k] = sanitize_text_field( $v );
      }
   }

  return $array;                                                       
}

$data = sanitize_price_array( $_POST['price_data']);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `map_deep()` to sanitize the array text field.

```
map_deep( wp_unslash( $_POST['price_data'] ) , 'sanitize_text_field' );
```

It may solve the issue.